# Jetpack Compose changing locales causing UI to change only on Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have xml files for all the strings of my app for it to be multi-lingual and I am using this function to change the language:

```
fun changeLanguage(language: Languages, context: Context) {
    val languageString = when (language) {
        Languages.ENGLISH -> "en"
        Languages.ITALIAN -> "it"
        Languages.FRENCH -> "fr"
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        context.getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java).applicationLocales =
            LocaleList.forLanguageTags(languageString)
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(
            LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(languageString)
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use this function, it causes the UI to expand and it happens only on android 12. Moreover, it happens only on the page shown in the gif I attached. I tried using the same function on another page and it doesn't affect UI.
[image]

Comment: When you change the locale of the app you must restart it to make your UI show properly